# Unsupported operand type(s), but can't find the error

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script that assembles a list of palindromes in a text file with words separated by breaks:

```py
def modified_palindromes(filename):
   """Returns a list of all words that spell the same backwards after moving the first letter to the end,as found in the file with the given name."""
    result = []
    
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
             for i in range(len(line.lower())):
                if line.lower()[i:(i+1)] == line.lower()[(len(line.lower())-i-1):len(line.lower()-i)]:
                    result.append(line)    
    return result

    pass  # TODO
```

However, I get an error in the line where I check if the ith letter counted from the left equals the ith letter counted from the right. Here's the error:

```
if line.lower()[i:(i+1)] == line.lower()[(len(line.lower())-i-1):(len(line.lower()-i))]:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

So I'm guessing that somewhere within this if-statement I am deducting an int from a string or vice versa, but I can't seem to find where. Len() should return an int, i is an int, 1 is an int, so where does it go wrong?

Comment: Hi. Which is the content of the file that you are trying to read? When you read a file, it does'nt matter that each line is a number. Python read it like a str.

Comment: `len(line.lower()-i)` should be `len(line.lower())-i`. Voting to close for typo. BTW, if you have a very long and complex line with an error, break that line down into several lines and Python will show the exact part that has the problem. Also, just storing `line.lower()` in temp variable will make that line 10x more readable (and a bit faster) and the error easier to spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are. Here `(line.lower()-i)`